# $.getJSON .always() method won't execute on HTTP error

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, getjson

I'm trying to retrieve some google calendar information using getJson. In some cases the calendars I'm trying to retrieve may or may not be available and I'll get either GET HTTP error 403 or 404, other times GET will be succesful. My problem is I need to execute some code even in the cases GET fails to receive the data. I thought that using the .always method would execute this code regardless but it turns out it won't execute when a 403 or 404 happens. I also tried specifically target this cases using .fail method with no success. Any idea?

Adding the code:

```
function AcquireGroupFeed(GroupDataBase) {

  // For each group the calendar information is aquired and, if the events are 
  // relevant they are added to the feed. 

  // The group's calendar URL
  var  CalUrl = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/" + GroupDataBase.calendarid + 
        "/public/full?alt=json-in-script&callback=?";

  // Acquiring the data from Google.        
  $.getJSON(CalUrl, function(data) {PushToEventFeed(data, GroupDataBase);})
            .always(function(){CheckAllGroupsAcquired();});

}
```

Comment: It does execute when there's an http error - there's either an issue with your code, or you're using an older jquery

Comment: Hi, Thelemitian, this sounds like this is very annoying. But it's difficult to diagnose these issues as a javascript issue. If you're getting a 4xx back, (in your case 403- forbidden, 404- not found) it  means that the server has received your request, but that you had something wrong with the request you sent. If you think that the server shouldn't have sent 4xx, post code, and this would be a good SO question. Otherwise, read http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10 Best wishes and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply guys! The 4xx errors are expected and are not the issue. This code is intended to get information from calendars owned by different organizations and generate a feed. So if an ornanization removes a calendar I'll get one of these errors and I need to make sure I handle that case correctly. I was hoping .always() would do the trick and, by Sam's comment seems it should but the method is not executed when an error does happens (is executed when no error happens) I might be doing something wrong but I don't find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently learned that, by using the $.ajax call instead of .getJSON I can handle the error when I fail to retrieve the URL. The timeout setup should be defined for the error to be handled:

```
$.ajax({
        url: URL,
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 3000,
        success: function( data ) { successFunction();},
        error: function( data ) { errorHandling(); }
      });
```

With this, I was able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are in fact doing a JSONP request, since the domain where the page is hosted is different from the one in the AJAX request. JSONP does not function by using the normal XMLHTTPRequest interface (it uses `script` elements), and it does not support failure callbacks.

If you look under the `error` option for the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function, you will see this note:

> This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests

The same applies to `$.getJSON` (since it is a wrapper for `$.ajax`).

If you need a failure callback, you will probably need to program it yourself, maybe based on a two-second timer, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks lonesomeday! Now, I'm using .always() instead of .fail() or .error() would your explanation apply too? Would .always() invoke .fail() or .error() upon an error occurrence and then fail to execute?

Comment: Oh never mind... I found the answer in the link you posted _In response to a successful request, the function's arguments are the same as those of .done(): data, textStatus, and the jqXHR object. For failed requests the arguments are the same as those of .fail(): the jqXHR object, textStatus, and errorThrown. Refer to deferred.always() for implementation details._